# How to execute ElasticSearch agg query from Apache Nifi using InvokeHTTP?

Tags: http, elasticsearch, lucene, apache-nifi

I want to execute the following query from Apache Nifi:

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "range": {
        "date_range": {
            "field": "Datetime",
            "ranges": [
                { 
                   "from": "2017-02-17T16:00:00Z||-1H/H",
                   "to": "2017-02-17T16:00:00Z||/H" 
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get the value of `doc_count`.

I tried to use `InvokeHTTP` and directly pasted the above-defined query into the field `HTTP Method`. I also set `Remote URL` to `http://localhost:9200`. I connected `InvokeHTTP` with `PutFile` in order to save a response on the disk. The relationship is `Response`.

When I run `InvokeHTTP`, it does not give me any error. However, it neither outputs any result (FlowFile for Response). I am sure that the result is not an empty set, because I tested this query with `curl`.

What is wrong with my approach? Should I define `HTTP Method` in some different way?

Answer (score 1):

For verbs like POST, PUT, and PATCH, you'd normally have the above JSON body as the content of a flow file and pass that to InvokeHttp, setting the correct verb and URL there. However the InvokeHttp documentation states that the message body will not be sent for a GET verb.

The good news is that the Elasticsearch REST API for the search endpoint supports both GET and POST. From their latest doc: "Both HTTP GET and HTTP POST can be used to execute search with body. Since not all clients support GET with body, POST is allowed as well."

I would set the content of a flow file to the above JSON body (perhaps using GenerateFlowFile or ReplaceText), then use POST as the verb.

Comment: Thanks, it works, excluding that I get thousands of response files instead of a single file. I have `GenerateFlowFile` with the content of my query `{...}` as `CustomText` field. In `InvokeHTTP` I set `Remote URL` to `http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search` and `HTTP Method` to `POST`. Do I miss something? How can I get a single FlowFile and just a field `doc_count`?

Comment: I finally solved the issue with the combination of `ListenHTTP`->`ReplateText`->`InvokeHTTP`. Now I only get a single file. However, if you can explain how to get a field `doc_count`, I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `JsonQueryElasticsearch` processor, which supports JSON elasticsearch queries.

[image: JsonQueryElasticsearch configuration]

Your query goes into the `Query` field.
The processor has `hits` and `aggregations` relations for you to process the result.